# How to initialize a dictionary unless it exist

Tags: python

I would like to create a nested dictionary. and I would to initialize a dict only if it doesn't exist.

```py
dict_main = {}
lis = [1, 2]
for a in range(2):
    for i in range(2):
        if not isinstance(dict_main[i], dict): #This line IS ONLY FOR DEMO, IT DOES NOT WORK
            dict_main[i] = {}
            dict_main[i]['a'] = lis[a]
        else:
            dict_main[i]['a'] = max(lis[b], dict_main[i]['a'])
print(dict_main)
```

I know this code doesn't make much sense but it's for explaining myself.

I hope my question is clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check if the key is present in your dictionary.

```
dict_main = {}
lis = [1, 2]
for a in range(2):
    for i in range(2):
        if i not in dict: #Checks if the key is contain on the dict, and if not, create it.
            dict_main[i] = {}
        if 'a' not in dict_main[i]:
            dict_main[i]['a'] = lis[a]
        else:
            dict_main[i]['a'] = max(lis[b], dict_main[i]['a'])
print(dict_main)
```